# how I can generate mac address increamental like 00:00:00:00:01 00:00:00:00:02

Tags: bash

how I can generate mac address incremental like

```
00:00:00:00:01
00:00:00:00:02
```

Answer (score 2):

You just increment a counter and use if for this

```
printf %0.16x "$counter" | sed -e 's/../&:/g' -e 's/:$//'
```

or
(uppercase)

```
printf %0.16X "$counter" | sed -e 's/../&:/g' -e 's/:$//'
```

For example:

```
$ counter=0;
$ while [ "$counter" -lt 11 ] ; do 
    let counter++;
    printf "%0.16x\n" "$counter" | sed -e 's/../&:/g' -e 's/:$//'; 
 done
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:04
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:05
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:06
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:09
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0a
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0b
```